# How to copy photos from PC/USB drive to an iPad with preserved folder structure

Tags: file-transfer, ios, ipad

My dad has a lot of photos on his windows surface laptop, and some others on a USB drive. They don't all fit on the laptop at the same time for space reasons.

The goal is easy: copy the photos from both sources to the iPad. I've never used Apple devices before, but it seems that the concept of a proper for system/explorer is not really a thing there.

Some of the things we tried were copying photos via iTunes. But that can't access the photos on the external drive. Same problem with Dropbox. And apparently you can't really just create a folder on the iPad and copy things there. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

There‘re apps for that:

PhotoSync is probably the best app to use, but I am not sure you are going to like to setup a samba server on a PC and you’ll definitely run into to space problems on the iPad sooner or later.

Probably the only future safe (non-technical) way to go here is to use a cloud service like iCloud or google drive - which means the photos will only be accessible when you’re online.

Comment: We are trying photosync right now and it would be a good solution. But it didn't preserve folders